# WebDriver, How do I prevent InternetExplorerDriver from taking control of the mouse pointer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, mouse

Whenever I run a WebDriver test in IE (using InternetExplorerDriver), where elements of a web page need to be clicked, the InternetExplorerDriver takes over my mouse.

This does not happen when I run my tests in either Chrome or Firefox.  Is there a way to prevent IE tests from taking control of the mouse pointer?

Example code that causes the mouse pointer to be 'stolen':

```
public void clickButtonNamed(String buttonName) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'" + buttonName + "')]")).click();
}

public void dragAndDropElement(WebElement source, WebElement target) throws InterruptedException {
    action.dragAndDrop(source,target).build().perform();
}

//IE Driver initialization
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS,true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

Comment: IEDriver initialization added.

Comment: @urbanaut What research have you done on this problem? There are numerous [blog](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/06/whats-wrong-with-internet-explorer.html) [posts](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html) that explain exactly what the IE driver is doing, and, more importantly, why. The nature of IE is such that there's no elegant approach for using so-called "native events" with IE.

Comment: @Jim  Quite a bit actually, I've actually read that article, and couple of your posts. The IEDriver has been so unpredictable and inconsistent that this is the only workaround (requiring window focus) that I've found to get it to click on elements with any consistency.  Unfortunately, by doing so, it takes over the mouse control (which does not happen with either chromedriver or firefoxdriver).

Comment: ...or perhaps it's just the inherent issues of IE itself (rather than the driver), either way it can be quite frustrating.

Comment: You could always turn off native events, as suggested by the second of the blog posts linked to above. The bottom line is that IE does not provide any high-fidelity way to simulate user input. The driver is limited by what the OS and the browser allow. If you have other methodologies for simulating user input, pull requests are gratefully accepted.

Comment: @JimEvans Is there another way I can communicate with you?  I have more questions about IE and Selenium.

Comment: I'm available most days (U.S. East Coast business hours) in the #selenium IRC channel on Freenode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you set this property `InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS` to `true`? This is why IEDriver asks IE to take control your pointer.

To fix it, simply remove it or set it to false. This was introduced in `2.28.0.3`, here's the quote from CHANGELOG:

> Introduced the "requireWindowFocus" capability into the IE driver. When used in conjunction with the "nativeEvents" capability, the
> driver will attempt     to bring the current IE window to the
> foreground before executing a mouse    or keyboard event.
>
> Also, when
> the requireWindowFocus capability is set to    true, advanced user
> interactions will now use the Windows SendInput() API to    execute
> the interactions. To enable this behavior, set the value of the
> requiresWindowFocus capability to "true" when creating an instance of
> the IE    driver. The default for this new capability is "false". This
> functionality    is currently considered extremely experimental; use
> at your own risk.

Comment: IE drives me crazy.  Unfortunately, if I don't include the 'REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS' capability, then I can't get the IEDriver to click on anything in the web app I'm testing. :-s

Comment: @urbanaut: Yes, you probably want to ask another question to describe your problem and see what's actually wrong with it. Meanwhile, probably need a separate environment for testing IE. For example, create a new Windows user and run on that account desktop.

Comment: Thanks, great advice, but I have tried that as well.  I created a Windows 7 VirtualBox and attempted to test exclusively for IE in that environment.  There too, I had the same problems with IE.

Comment: @urbanaut: Sorry, I mean run in a separate environment with `REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS` enabled. Then you don't care about if it's taking over mouse pointer or not.

Comment: Oh true, that may be what I'll have to do.

Comment: In my case, to set REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS as FALSE resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using this setting will avoid IE to take over the mouse control while performing actions -

InternetExplorerOptions ieOp = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOp.disableNativeEvents();